# Character creation for fun. Is this strange?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, dungeons-and-dragons

After asking a few questions and some of the responses I've received it has made me wonder. 
   Does anyone else enjoy creating characters, unique weapons or gear, or creatures just for fun and to have on hand later of a situation pops up and you think "Oh! Ive got just the thing for this!". 
     I ask because most seem to be of the opinion of waiting for a game then creating something for that one, and not worrying about it until then.
      So in short does anyone else enjoy creating these things just because?

Comment: This question seems more like a forum topic than an objectively answerable question. You might have better luck asking this on an RPG forum.

Comment: Further @QuadraticWizard's comment, we have a curated [list of forums here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)